# How do I improve performance when downloading files from an Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to download a 19 Mb file from an an Amazon S3 bucket using Amazon SDK but it eventually takes a lot more time than Amazon CLI. The code I am using is below:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                    .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                    .build();

s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketName", "path/fileName.zip"), new File("localFileName.zip"));
```

**If we compare downloading timings of both mechanisms then:** Amazon SDK took around 9 min to get it downloaded whereas Amazon CLI took around 5 seconds.

**Is there a way where we can decrease downloading time while using Amazon SDK?**

Answer (score 2):

First issue here is you are using the OLD SDK for Java which is V1. Amazon recommends moving to V2 as best practice.

To learn about AWS SDK for Java V2, see:

[Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

Here is the code you should use to download an object from an Amazon S3 bucket. This is the [V2 S3TransferManager](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/transfermanager/GetObject.java):

```
package com.example.transfermanager;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.FileDownload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class GetObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - the object to download (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - the path where the file is written (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
              System.out.println(usage);
              System.exit(1);
        }

        long MB = 1024;
        String bucketName = args[0];
        String objectKey =  args[1];
        String objectPath =  args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3TransferManager transferManager =  S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3ClientConfiguration(cfg ->cfg.region(region)
                        .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
                        .targetThroughputInGbps(20.0)
                        .minimumPartSizeInBytes(10 * MB))
                .build();

        downloadObjectTM(transferManager, bucketName,  objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Object was successfully downloaded using the Transfer Manager.");
        transferManager.close();
    }

    public static void downloadObjectTM(S3TransferManager transferManager, String  bucketName, String objectKey, String objectPath ) {
        FileDownload download =
                transferManager.downloadFile(d -> d.getObjectRequest(g -> g.bucket(bucketName).key(objectKey))
                        .destination(Paths.get(objectPath)));
        download.completionFuture().join();

    }
}
```

I just ran this code and downloaded a PDF that is 25 MB in seconds...

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution but it actually not working for me it's not able to pick credentials from environment variables or from system properties. `Exception in thread "Thread-0" software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).`

Comment: You have not setup your dev project to use Java V2 properly then. Check the credentials section in the AWS Java V2 DEV Guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: I have created a default profile on my local machine and am able to view credentials in the aws folder. As I am able to use `aws cli` commands locally so I feel credentials are properly set. The only thing this V2 version is not able to read it, because V1 is able to work properly without any issues.

Comment: Even on the EC2 instance, I am getting similar issues while doing V1 code we are actually no need to specify any credentials it is retrieving internally from IAM policies I guess. But for V2 we have to specify right?

Comment: For the Above code - i set up creds using Environment variables and it works perfectly. Have you tried running this code on your local dev machine?

Comment: And for this V2 example, are you are using this POM  - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/pom.xml

Comment: Ohh great it is working. Got the Amazon SDK Version 2 working now. Thanks @smac2020

Comment: I am glad to hear you got it working!!